# Facebook sdk 4.1.0 Logout not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, logout

I am using following code to do logout from the app.

```
   [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];

   if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
      [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
      [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
   }
```

Still its picking old profile to login. If i kill the app and start again then it works fine.

Any suggestion what i am doing wrong ?

Login Code -

```
         FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];         
     [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_birthday",@"public_profile",@"user_friends",@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
           // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
           // Handle cancellations
        } else {
           if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {

              // Do work
              NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",result.token.tokenString]]];

              //Start the request for the data
              [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                 NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [jsonString JSONValue];
                 [self getFBUserDetailFinished:jsonDict];
              }];
           }
        }
     }];
```

Comment: Are you saying this code does login with old profile instead of loging out? Please explain step-by-step scenario after this code executed.

Comment: I am doing login with login manager all works fine, And there is a button to logout current profile. For that button i am using this code. And when again i am login its picking previous login profile not the current logged in profile. If i kill the app and start again then its picking current profile..Hope you got now...

Comment: I'd doubt it might be about your login method rather than logout, so could you show your login code as well?.

Comment: you open safari browser or webview?

Comment: @SanitLee added Login code.

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya its opening for login in the Facebook app

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
```

**Another way** : You get facebook userinformation after logout method call and you second time loging then not problem fetch in fetch user data.

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
                 [login logOut];
             }
         }
     }];
}

-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];

    }

}
```